# Microsoft Azure text translation API translation error

Tags: azure, text-analytics-api

I use the text translation api to translate a word from zh-Hans to ko. Such as "你好",the result is "정말". The result is error.The correct result is "안녕하세요".
And from ko to zh-Hans,"정말" -->"真的".

Answer (score 1):

Kindly drop your comment on Microsoft support page; it will help them develop the translator algorithm to serve you and I better.